# Is it possible for a link to call javascript that exists on the page it directs to?

Tags: javascript, iframe

My situation is that I have a video gallery where when a user clicks a video thumbnail, Javascript shows a video and hides all of the others. So only one video is ever displayed at one time, but they're all there, just hidden. The problem is I want to link to the video gallery and have a specific video be called when they hit the videos page from this link. But since the javascript is all on that page itself, while the links on that page work, for an external link pointing in, I don't know how to activate that javascript.

I have another video gallery that is set up differently but has the same problem. I have videos embedded on individual pages that display in an iframe when a user clicks a link on the outside page. But linking in I don't know how to change the iframe that is in the page that I am linking to.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the video ID in the URL.

```
http://mysite.com/videos?videoId=xxxxxx
```

Then you can use JS to get the ID out of the URL. I like to use this [`gup()`](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html) function to get the URL parameter and display the video accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could check [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location). For example, if a link to a video is  `http://www.example.com/#myCoolVidNr1`, `window.location.hash` contains `#myCoolVidNr1`.